# Babel ignores ES6 inside React dangerouslySetInnerHtml script tag

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm building a progressively enhanced React app which is completely server rendered (there is no JS bundle sent to the browser right now), sent down to the browser and then progressively enhanced using jQuery, inserted into the HTML by using `<script dangerouslySetInnerHtml= {{ __html:` // ES6 code `}} />`. However, Babel seems to be ignoring any ES6 inside these script tags, which is an issue as my application has to support some older browsers which has no support for ES6.

Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

  const jsScript = `
    // ES6 code like arrow functions, spread operator, destructuring etc
    // It mainly uses jQuery to get the elements and work on them
  ` 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        lots of content which will need progressive enhancement
        <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: jsScript }} /> 
      </div>
    )
  }

}
```

The ES6 inside `jsScript` is sent to the browser as ES6, not transpiled ES5, which is fine for newer browsers but fails on older browsers. How can I get Webpack/Babel to transpile it?

Also this is simply a prototype - eventually the code will be progressively enhanced in a lot more solid way but for now this works. Thanks!

Comment: Depending on how `Babel` is on the page, you could try to use `Babel.transform('your code as a string')`.  `transform` will output the transpiled code.

Comment: @DavinTryon thanks - do you know if there's any way to make it transpile automatically in Webpack or .babelrc? Don't want to have to do that in all the components where I'm doing this

Comment: I don't think there is a way because when Babel parses into the AST, the code will be a string.

Comment: The content of a template literal is basically a string. Babel will not transpile strings inside of your code. This seems to be the wrong approach anyway. Have you considered putting the code inside a function and execute the function when the component was rendered?